# Queue Fairness and Messaging Servers

Tags: rabbitmq, jms, message-queue, messaging

I'm looking to solve a problem that I have with the FIFO nature of messaging severs and queues. In some cases, I'd like to distribute the messages in a queue to the pool of consumers on a criteria other than the message order it was delivered in. Ideally, this would prevent users from hogging shared resources in the system. Take this overly simplified scenario:

- There is a feature within an application where a user can empty their trash can.
- This event dispatches a DELETE message for each item in trash can
- The consumers for this queue invoke a web service that has a rate limited API.

Given that each user can have very large volumes of messages in their trash can, what options do we have to allow concurrent processing of each trash can without regard to the enqueue time? It seems to me that there are a few obvious solutions:

- Create a separate queue and pool of consumers for each user
- Randomize the message delivery from a single queue to a single pool of consumers

In our case, creating a separate queue and managing the consumers for each user really isn't practical. It can be done but I think I really prefer the second option if it's reasonable. We're using RabbitMQ but not necessarily tied to it if there is a technology more suited to this task.

I'm entertaining the idea of using Rabbit's message priorities to help randomize delivery. By randomly assigning a message a priority between 1 and 10, this should help distribute the messages. The problem with this method is that the messages with the lowest priority may be stuck in the queue forever if the queue is never completely emptied. I thought I could use a TTL on the message and then re-queue the message with an escalated priority but I noticed this in the [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html):

> Messages which should expire will still only expire from the head of
>   the queue. This means that unlike with normal queues, even per-queue
>   TTL can lead to expired lower-priority messages getting stuck behind
>   non-expired higher priority ones. These messages will never be
>   delivered, but they will appear in queue statistics.

I fear that I may heading down the rabbit hole with this approach. I wonder how others are solving this problem. Any feedback on creative routing, messaging patterns, or any alternative solutions would be appreaciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I ended up taking a page out of the network router handbook. This a problem they routers need to solve to allow fair traffic patterns. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tEU9b5N53fM) has a good breakdown of the problem and the solution.

The translation of the problem into my domain:

[image: Unfair Flows with a Single FIFO Queue]

And the solution:

[image: Fair Flows with Multiple FIFO Queues and a Load Balancer]

The load balancer is a wrapper around a channel and a known number of queues that uses a weighted algorithm to balance between messages received on each queue. We found a [really interesting article/implementation](http://nithril.github.io/amqp/2015/07/05/fair-consuming-with-rabbitmq/) that seems to be working well so far.

With this solution, I can also prioritize workspaces after messages have been published to increase their throughput. That's a really nice feature.

The biggest challenge ahead of me is management of the queues. There will be too many queues to leave bound to the exchange for an extended period of time. I'm working on some tools to manage their lifecycle.

Comment: brilliant! well done, adapt from networking to messaging in software. :) i'm going to have to remember this one the next time i run into a similar situation

Comment: This is a very nice answer, kudos!

Answer (score 4):

One solution could be to interpose a [Resequencer](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/Resequencer.html).  The principle is outlined in the diag in that link.  In your case, something like:

- The app dispatches its DELETE messages into the delete queue as originally.
- The Resequencer (a new component you write) is interposed between the original publishers and original consumers.  It:

  - pulls messages off the DELETE queue into memory
  - places them into (in-memory) queues-by-user
  - republishes them to a new queue (eg FairPriorityDeleteQueue), round-robinning to interleave fairly any messages from different original users
  - limits its republish rate into FairPriorityDeleteQueue, either such that the length of FairPriorityDeleteQueue (obtainable via polling the rabbitmq management api periodically) never exceeds some integer you choose N, or limited to some rate related to the rate-limited delete API the consumers use.
  - doesn't ack any message it pulled off the original DELETE queue, until it's republished it to FairPriorityDeleteQueue (so you never lose a message)
- The original consumers subscribe instead to FairPriorityDeleteQueue.

  - You set the preFetchCount on these consumers fairly low (<10), to prevent them in turn bulk-buffering the contents of FairPriorityDeleteQueue in memory.

--

Some points to watch:

- Rate- or length-limiting publishing into and/or drawing messages out of FairPriorityDeleteQueue is essential.  If you don't limit, Resequencer may just hand messages on as fast as it receives them, limiting the potential for resequencing.
- Resequencer of course acts as a kind of in-memory buffer while resequencing.  If the original publishers can publish *very* large numbers of messages in to the queue suddenly, you may need to memory-limit the Resequencer process so that it doesn't ingest more than it can hold.

*Your particular scenario is greatly helped by the fact that you have an external factor (the final delete API) limiting throughput.*  Without such an extrinsic limiting factor, it is much harder to choose the optimum parameters for such a resequencer, to balance throughput-versus-resequencing in a particular environment.

Comment: Ultimately, I've ended up with a solution that does end up resequencing the messages from different queues via a load balancer but it avoids the extra queue and resequencing in memory. I'll add an answer shortly.

Comment: @MikeCantrell Right. Agree that this avoids the extra queue.  From a quick skim of the article, it looks like the code uses _past_ queue content as a guide to priority for pulling messages off the queues? (Is that right?)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think a resequencer is needed in this case. Maybe it is, if you need to ensure the items are deleted in a specific order. But that only comes into play when you send multiple messages at roughly the same time and need to guarantee order on the consumer end.

You should also avoid the timeout scenario, for the reasons you've mentioned. timeout is meant to tell RabbitMQ that a message doesn't need to be processed - or that it needs to be routed to a dead letter queue so that i can be processed by some other code. while you might be able to make timeout work, i don't think it's a good choice.

Priorities may solve part of the problem, but could introduce a scenario where files never get processed. if you have a priority 1 message sitting back in the queue somewhere, and you keep putting priority 2, 3, 5, 10, etc. into the queue, the 1 might not be processed. the timeout doesn't solve this, as you've noted.

For my money, I would suggest a different approach: sending delete requests serially, for a single file.

that is, send 1 message to delete 1 file. wait for a response to say it's done. then send the next message to delete the next file.

here's why i think that will work, and how to manage it:

### Long-Running Workflow, Single File Delete Requests

In this scenario, I would suggest taking a multi-step approach to the problem using the idea of a "saga" (aka [a long-running workflow object](http://derickbailey.com/2015/08/10/managing-workflow-in-long-running-javascript-processes/)).

when a user requests to delete their trashcan, you send a single message through rabbitmq to the service that can handle the delete process. that service creates an instance of the saga for that user's trashcan.

the saga gathers a list of all files in the trashcan that need to be deleted. then it starts to send the requests to delete the individual files, one at a time.

with each request to delete a single file, the saga waits for the response to say the file was deleted.

when the saga receives the message to say the previous file has been deleted, it sends out the next request to delete the next file.

once all the files are deleted, the saga updates itself and any other part of the system to say the trash can is empty.

### Handling Multiple Users

When you have a single user requesting a delete, things will happen fairly quickly for them. they will get their trash emptied soon.

```
u1 = User 1 Trashcan Delete Request

|u1|u1|u1|u1|u1|u1|u1|u1|u1|u1done|
```

when you have multiple users requesting a delete, the process of sending one file delete request at a time means each user will have an equal chance of getting the next file delete.

```
u1 = User 1 Trashcan Delete Request
u2 = User 2 Trashcan Delete Request

|u1|u2|u1|u1|u2|u2|u1|u2|u1|u2|u2|u1|u1|u1|u2|u2|u1|u2|u1|u1done|u2|u2done|
```

This way, there will be shared use of the resources to delete the files. Over-all, it will take a little longer for each person's trashcan to be emptied, but they will see progress sooner and that's an important aspect of people thinking the system is fast / responsive to their request.

### Optimizing Small File Set vs Large File Set

In a scenario where you have a small number of users with a small number of files, the above solution may prove to be slower than if you deleted all the files at once. after all, there will be more messages sent across rabbitmq - at least 2 for every file that needs to be deleted (one delete request, one delete confirmation response)

To optimize this further, you could do a couple of things:

1. have a minimum trashcan size before you split up the work like this. below that minimum, you just delete it all at once
2. chunk the work into groups of files, instead of one at a time. maybe 10 or 100 files would be a better group size, than 1 file at a time

Either (or both) of these solutions would help to improve the over-all performance of the process by reducing the number of messages being sent, and batching the work a bit.

You would need to do some testing in your real scenario to see which of these (or maybe both) would help and at what settings.

### Many Users Problem

There's one additional problem you may face - many users. If you have 2 or 3 users requesting deletes, it won't be a big deal.

But if you have 100 or 1000 users requesting deletes, it could take a very long time for an individual to get their trashcan emptied.

You may need to have a higher level controlling process for this situation, where all requests to empty trashcans would be managed by yet another Saga. This saga would rate-limit the number of active trashcan-deletion sagas.

For example, if you have 10 active requests for deleting trashcans, the rate-limiting saga would only start 3 of them and it would wait for one to finish before starting the next one.

Again, you would need to test your actual scenario to see if this is needed and see what the limits should be, for performance reasons.

---

There may be additional scenarios that have to be considered in your actual scenario, but I hope this gets you down the path! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I won't be able to achieve a decent delete rate for each trash can unless I run them concurrently. For instance, it would take over 8 minutes to delete a trash can with 10k messages at 50ms a message. Batching could help in this scenario but I have the same condition where each unit of work needs to be done on different server (due to some heavy file IO and CPU match).

Comment: having the work done on separate systems is easy enough. each consumer sets a consumer prefetch limit of 1, and does not ack the message until the work is completed. but i can see how this would still be problematic if you're batching 10 items and each item needs to run on a separate server.