# How can I implement round-robin prioritization in a celery queue?

Tags: python, celery

I have a celery queue that does computation tasks that take about a minute each.

If one user_id submits 10 jobs at the same time, they expect to wait 10 minutes.

If another user_id submits a single job 30 seconds later, I don't want them to wait 10 minutes before it can start.

In effect I'd like celery to treat tasks from each user_id as a separate queue, and rotate around any user_ids currently submitting tasks.  Is this a thing?

Everything is working nicely in celery as normal, but I haven't done any prioritization of tasks, as I don't yet know a good scheme to achieve what I want.

Comment: You may have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398634/queue-fairness-and-messaging-servers

Comment: That's a really good explanation of the problem and topic generally.  Do you know if Celery has implemented anything like this, or do I need to think in terms of writing a separate queue and worker that can implement the per-user FiFo model outlined in the Saga design?

Comment: As far as I know, Celery does not give this functionality out-of-box.

Comment: ok - thanks.  That saves some time hunting.  I'll get going with some FiFos....